# C# autocomplete combobox trigger SelectionChangeCommited

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I'm having problems with the autocomplete property of a combobox. I want to trigger the `SelectionChangeCommited` event every time I choose an item using the autocomplete but it's not working. The only way the event is triggered is when I use the mouse click and select an option or when the combobox is focused and I use arrow keys on the keyboard. How do I achieve this behaviour using the autocomplete property?

My combo has these properties set:

```
AutoCompleteMode = SuggestAppend
AutoCompleteSource = ListItems
FormattingEnabled = True
```

The items in my combo are set with a datasource.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want it to register a change when you start typing:

Call the SelectionChangeCommited event from the TextChanged event.

If you've never done this, the most basic example I could find was on the .net forums [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f8695771-5663-43da-85d8-2aeac9865e0f) Granted, the methods shown there are generalities, but is very simple to understand and apply to your code.

**EDIT FIXED (as of most recent comment):**

Still tie the events together, but instead of using TextChanged, which would occur ever time you type, use the SelectedIndexChanged, which occurs when you use the mouse to select an auto suggested item.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Not when I start typing, I want to trigger the event when selecting the suggested option.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're looking at doing. You're still using the mouse to select, but when you click the "suggested" option, it doesn't register that as SelectionChangeCommited, correct?

Comment: It isn't triggered let me check this.

Comment: It's cause it isn't the correct code, I pasted the wrong one, my apologies. I fixed it (and tested it too, it worked for me). Also the reason the other guys code doesn't work is cause the event he's calling code in is run when the control itself is validated with the load of the form itself.

Comment: You try the edited code above yet? I wasn't sure since I posted it late Friday for you, let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Sorry for the late, I wasn't in town this weekend but now I'm back. In fact your code is working, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

you canuse a trick and call `comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted`
in Validated event

when ever text in combobox changes and user leave the combo box it will be fired

```
  private void comboBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender, e);

    }
```

Comment: Yes I checked, the solution to my problem was the answer above, thanks anyway